# How can I make my API in Azure communicate with a service?

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, asp.net-core-3.1

Disclaimer: I have zero experience with Azure, or any cloud solutions whatsoever, so I may be asking a stupid question; I have, however, been given this task at work, so I have to do it.

My problem is as follows: I have a REST API project written in .NET Core. It is hosted as an App Service on Azure. Some endpoints in the API have to communicate with a service (a MS Orleans service) and send some data to it. Said service is also hosted on Azure as an App Service on the same Resource Group. The way this solution has been developed is that the API knows the IP address of the service, and tries to connect with the service using said IP address. It works locally, but when I deploy it on Azure, I get exceptions. I tried changing the IP address to the inbound address provided by Azure, but it didn't work either. I'm getting the following error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ZEl.png)

What should I do to make the services communicate? I will thankful for any tips.

Comment: Add tge error as text to make it available for index engines,

Answer (score 0):

If we would like to connect with Silo from Azure Web App, we need to assign both Azure Web App and the worker role hosting the Silo to an Azure Virtual Network.

Refer to [MS Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/) to understand about Azure Websites Virtual Network Integration.

we can assign the cloud service to the virtual network by modifying the ServiceConfiguration file.

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
  <VirtualNetworkSite name="virtual-network-name" />
  <AddressAssignments>
    <InstanceAddress roleName="role-name">
      <Subnets>
        <Subnet name="subnet-name" />
      </Subnets>
    </InstanceAddress>
  </AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Also make sure the Silo endpoints are configured.

```
<Endpoints>
  <InternalEndpoint name="OrleansSiloEndpoint" protocol="tcp" port="11111" />
  <InternalEndpoint name="OrleansProxyEndpoint" protocol="tcp" port="30000" />
</Endpoints>
```

If the Web App is having difficulty connecting to the Silo:
•   Make sure you have at least two roles, or two instances of one role in your Azure Cloud Service, or the InternalEndpoint firewall rules may not be generated.
•   Check that both the Web App and the Silo are using the same ClusterId and ServiceId.
•   Make sure the network security group is set up to allow internal virtual network connections. If you haven't got one you can create and assign one easily using the following PowerShell:

```
New-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "Default" -Location "North Europe"
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "Default" | Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupToSubnet -VirtualNetworkName "virtual-network-name" -SubnetName "subnet-name"
```

Refer to [Orleans docs](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/deployment/azure_web_apps_with_azure_cloud_services.html) for more info